# Regex to find all anchor tag links

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

Just to get this out of the way from the start, I have read *that* question, and I totally get that generally it's a bad idea, and that there are other better ways.

However, for my very simple use case, which is to retrieve all the anchor tag links on a page, I would've thought the following regex would suffice, and be far simpler and faster than a full blown HTML parser:

```
href="(.+)"
```

Now, am I overlooking some obvious fatal flaw, or would this be a good enough option for my very simple use case?

Comment: Well, `document.querySelectorAll('a')` will grab the links, and then it is simple to loop them and get their `href` value

Comment: And [here we go again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3136474)...

Comment: `<script>href="foo"</script>` Now what?

Comment: @Dinei you clearly didn’t read the question, because OP mentioned that. It’s a legitimate question. OP is not trying to do any complex parsing; they are asking about getting very specific items using regex.

Comment: And btw, your quotes `"` might not work as their might be values with single quotes too

Comment: You also might want to rephrase your title, since you don't actually parse HTML but rather look for a string combination

Comment: HTML works with single quotes as well as spacing and additional links besides URLS so, `href ='tel:123457890'` is valid. However, you wouldn't pick this up b/c you need to grab spaces between the equals and href as well as single quotes. Your regex may work if you are controlling the html that you are also reading, but it would not work in the real world where you don't control that data.

Comment: @Marathon55 I've read the question, just wanted to add some link to *that* mentioned question. And the title seems like a clickbait to me, anyway.

Comment: @Dinei that’s fair.

Comment: @Dinei Fair enough, I guess the title could be clearer - it certainly wasn't intended as clickbait

Comment: No. Because *Regular Expressions* are used for parsing *regular* languages. HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: No, it’s a bit more complicated than that.

Why? That will likely grab more than the anchor tag links because `href` is used for more than just anchor tags. See [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp) for some examples.

There may also be tags with an `href` attribute which are commented out in the HTML.

Also, it could be in a JavaScript string for elements that get dynamically added to a page such as

```
var newElement = '<a href="www.example.com">My Page</a>
```

There are quirks you’d need to account for such as the ones mentioned in the comments by LGSon and Daniel Gale, amongst others, but this is probably enough to answer your question - *no, it’s not that simple*.